Pinescript: Reduce decimal places for format.volume?
I'm using format.volume to clean up huge numbers for avg. volume, $ volume and float.
I'd like to just have the whole integers (or maybe 1 decimal point). Is there a way to control this?
Whether float is 39M, or 39.096M doesn't seem like it would make a lot of difference...
[table.cell(StockData, 0, 6, 'Vol ' + str.tostring(AvgVol, format.volume), bgcolor = AvgVolCondition, text_size = size.small)
table.cell(StockData, 0, 7, '$Vol ' + str.tostring(AvgDVol, format.volume), bgcolor = AvgDVolCondition, text_size = size.small)
table.cell(StockData, 0, 8, 'Float ' + str.tostring(FloatShares, format.volume), bgcolor = FloatCondition, text_size = size.small)][1]

